# How to post the template into NIFI from local drive using Postman?

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi

I have using 0.6.1 binary source.

I am new to nifi rest api.

How to post the templates from local drive into NIFI UI using Rest API in windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload templates from Postman using the following settings:

- Method: `POST`
- Request URL: `http://yournifiserver:8080/nifi-api/controller/templates`
- Body:

  - Select `form-data`
  - Add key/value pair with key `template`, set the value type to file and browse for your local file.

Then Send.

[image]